# PHP: Как спарсить текст с ряда сайтов, полностью очистив тексты от их индивидуального форматирования, стилей, тегов, html?

Tags: php, html, парсер, file-get-contents, веб-скрейпинг

Паршу в качестве эксперимента группы сайтов. Тексты с их страниц мне нужно объединить в один текст. У нужных страниц разных сайтов индивидуальное форматирование.

Если забираю информацию регулярным выражением по `<p></p>`, то многие сайты выпадают, потому что у них не таким тегом все сделано.
Если пытаюсь очистить тексты от лишних элементов, например, вставок Youtube-роликов, то `strip_tags` только часть элементов удаляет.

Некоторые вещи в `iframe`, некоторые в дивах, внутри дивов, содержащих другие дивы. Особенностей уйма.

Подскажите, как с ряда сайтов спарсить очищенные от всего тексты? У кого есть такой опыт? Буду благодарен за любой совет...

Comment: Получить просто текст без тегов можно в [tag:bs4], причесать пробелы и прочие аномалии через [tag:regex]. Если особенностей уйма, универсального решения никогда не будет.

Comment: `strip_tags()` вернет вам голый текст. приведите пример, когда он удаляет только часть?

Comment: @teran http://f90577wq.beget.tech/cyanotis вот в этой странице текст пропущен через strip_tegs(http://f90577wq.beget.tech/cyanotis), видео и некоторые другие элементы остались, в таком виде были положены в базу

Comment: ну если вы саму ссылку в `strip_tags` пихали то не удивительно, ибо функция на входе требует контент, а не ссылку

Comment: @teran не, не ссылку, конечно, а спаршенный file_get_contents контент html страницы